# Can someone clear up this semantic proof of quantification logic?

Tags: quantification

The idea is to proof validity of

∃x(Fx ^ Gx) / ∃xFx

To do this I understand you assume invalid and get a contradiction. I have the answer but I don't understand the wording

> ∃x(Fx ^ Gx) is true-in-I, which means some object o∈D satisfies Fx ^ Gx, which means o is 
>   such that both o∈ext(F) and o∈ext(G).
>
> ∃xFx is false-in-I, which means every object o`∈D is such that o`∉ext(F).
>
> Since what holds of o` holds of everything in the domain of I, and since o∉D, o∉ext(F). 
>   Contradiction, so there is no such interpretation. Thus valid.

what I don't get is the last statement "since what holds of o' holds of everything in the domain of I" how does that go to "since o∉D" when we are talking about o' and not o and we had established o is contained in D already (I get we need the contradiction, but from where was this generated?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with "intuition" :

> **if** there is a black cat, **then** there is a cat

is an argument that "sound" quite correct.

To prove it "semantically" we have to assume an *interpretation* **I** in which the premise is true.

This means that there is an object **o** of the domain of the interpretation **I** for which both *F* and *G* holds.

But this implies that for that object **o** the "property" *F* holds, and this boils down to say that in **I** there exists an *x* such that *F(x)* is *true*.

Thus, being **I** an interpretation whatever, we have proved it for **all** interpretations; i.e. in every interpretation in which the premise is true, also the conclusion is, and this is the definition of *logical consequence* :

> A ⊨ B.

---

*Note*

In proving it by contradiction, we have to assume that the conclusion ∃xFx is false; this amount to saying that for **every** object **x** in the domain **D** of the interpretation, we have that *F* does not hold for it.

But this is in contradiction with the fact implied by the assumption that there is **o ∈ D** such that *F* holds for it.

Answer (score 1):

'o∉D' is a typo, which should be corrected to 'o∈D'. The point simply is this: Since by assumption ∃xFx is false in I we have o*∉ext(F) for all o*∈D. We already know that there is some o∈D. So, o∉ext(F). But wait! Since o satisfies Fx&Gx we have o∈ext(F). So, o∈ext(F) and o∉ext(F). Contradiction.

Actually I think it more elegant to prove the contrapositive. If no o'∈D is such that o'∈ext(F), then it's not the case that both o'∈ext(F) and o'∈ext(G). So, nothing from D satisfies Fx&Gx. So,∃x(Fx & Gx) is false in I.